# Combinar filas de un data frame según columna

Tags: r, dataframe

Soy un principiante en el mundo de la programación y me encuentro con este problema:
Tengo un data frame sobre pacientes y enfermedades y el objetivo es encontrar patrones que puedan predecir la enfermedad. Para poder utilizar arules entiendo que lo primero que tengo que hacer es organizar el data frame. Así, esta es la estructura (son 9700 pacientes y 35 diagnósticos diferentes):

```
Paciente     Patologia

 1         Sarcopenia

 1          Obesidad

 2          Sarcopenia

 2          Lupus

 2          Dolor
```

Quisiera agrupar todos los diagnósticos de cada paciente de tal manera que la estructura pasara a ser la siguiente:

```
Paciente       Patología

1              Sarcopenia, Obesidad

2              Sarcopenia, Lupus, Dolor
```

De esta forma, más adelante podría crear una matriz de este tipo:

```
Paciente       Sarcopenia     Obesidad   Lupus     Dolor
1                1             1         0        0
2                1             0         1        1
```

He probado el siguiente código y obtengo un mensaje de error que no comprendo.

```
Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% summarise_all(list(trimws(paste(., collapse = ""))))
```

> Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") : nombres de variables se limitan a 10000 bytes

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Buenas Iker, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Debes añadir las investigaciones y pruebas que hayas realizado para que te podamos ayudar con el problema que tienes. Revisate [ask] para saber como realizar una buena pregunta en el sitio y que ésta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Tambien puedes realizar el [tour] y asi obtienes tu primera medalla. :)

Comment: Gracias Marc, he editado el mensaje y añadido una de las pruebas que he hecho (la que creo que más se aproxima a la solución).

Comment: Oye Iker, te he dado un +1 por que tu pregunta me pareció muy útil y bien formulada, invito al resto de la comunidad a hacer lo mismo. Sigue así!

Answer (score 2):

El error que tienes es irreproducible por que tiene que ver con cantidad de datos que el ejemplo que has compartido no tiene, al respecto lo único que puedo decir es que en R los nombres están limitados 10.000 bytes de longitud que evidentemente tu código parecería estar superándolo. De todas formas, entiendo que lo que buscas en realidad es algo así:

**Concatenar las patologías en una cadena:**

```
Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms %>% 
    group_by(PatientID) %>% 
    summarise(Patologias = paste0(Patologia, collapse = ",")) 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  PatientID Patologias            
      <int> <chr>                 
1         1 Sarcopenia,Obesidad   
2         2 Sarcopenia,Lupus,Dolor
```

**o bien, también puede que busques agrupar en una lista:**

```
Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms %>% 
    group_by(PatientID) %>% 
    summarise(Patologias = list(Patologia))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  PatientID Patologias
      <int> <list>    
1         1 <chr [2]> 
2         2 <chr [3]>
```

Pero para la salida final que buscas es mucho más sencillo usar directamente el verbo `spread()` "esparcir" de la siguiente forma:

```
Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms %>% 
    mutate(valor=1) %>% 
    spread(Patologia, valor, fill=0)

  PatientID Dolor Lupus Obesidad Sarcopenia
1         1     0     0        1          1
2         2     1     1        0          1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, de verdad. Al emplear el comando spread() obtengo el siguiente mensaje: Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation. Built. Entiendo que es porque uso Mac. De todas formas, con el comentario de @Robert (empleando dcast) he logrado lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias a lo dos!

Comment: @IkerVillanueva, ese mensaje normalmente aparece cuando instalas un paquete y en vez de ejecutar `install.packages()` ejecutas  `installed.packages()`. El primero, efectivamente instala un paquete, el segundo solo lista los paquetes instalados.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho. Me he dado cuenta de que esa estructura no me sirve. Con el comando Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% summarise(Patologias = paste0(Patologia, collapse = ","))  obtengo las variables agrupadas por comas en la misma celda, pero (creo que) necesito que estén separadas por celdas (cada uno de los síntomas en una celda). Estoy atascado en este punto, ¿Podrías ayudarme, por favor?

Comment: Iker, el último código que te dí, transforma todas las patologías en columnas independientes con un 1 y 0, esa salida no te sirve? ¿que buscas? ¿Una columna "Dummy" por cada patología y en cada celda el nombre de éstas?

Comment: gracias por responder. He formulado la pregunta de forma más concreta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273034/estructurar-un-dataframe-para-arules

Answer (score 2):

Puedes conseguir lo mismo con `dcast` de `reshape2`

```
Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms=structure(list(PatientID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), Patologia = c("C", "F", "G", "A", "B", "D", 
"F", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "D", "E", "G", "H", "F", "A", "B", 
"F", "G", "H", "A", "G", "B", "C", "A", "B", "E", "G", "C", "E", 
"H", "C", "G", "A", "G", "A", "C", "D", "G")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L
), class = "data.frame")
library(reshape2)
dcast(Sarcopenia_PatientSymptoms, PatientID  ~ Patologia, fun.aggregate = length)

#    PatientID A B C D E F G H
# 1          1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
# 2          2 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
# 3          3 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 4          4 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
# 5          6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# 6          7 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
# 7          8 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
# 8          9 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 9         10 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
# 10        11 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
# 11        12 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
# 12        14 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
# 13        15 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
```