# Estructurar un dataframe para arules

Tags: r, estructuras-de-datos, matrices-asociativas, dataframe

Tengo que realizar un análisis de las posibles asociaciones (usando arules) entre patologías para determinar si están relacionadas. Parto de un dataframe con 9700 pacientes y 35 patologías. El dataframe tiene esta estructura:

```
Paciente     Patologia
 1         Sarcopenia
 1          Obesidad
 2          Sarcopenia
 2          Lupus
 2          Dolor
```

Gracias a la ayuda de @PatricioMoracho y @Robert he conseguido que la estructura pase a ser la siguiente:

```
Paciente       Sarcopenia     Obesidad   Lupus     Dolor
1                1             1         0        0
2                1             0         1        1
```

Ahora, para empezar a usar arules el código que he empleado es el siguiente:

```
tr <- as(Matriz2, "transactions")
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error in discretizeDF(from) : Problem with column Abdominal_Obesity
>   Error in discretize(x = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   :    The calculated breaks are: 0, 0, 0, 1   Some breaks are not
>   unique. Change the number of breaks or consider using method 'fixed'.
>   Además: Warning message: Column(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
>   29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36 not logical or factor. Applying default
>   discretization (see '? discretizeDF').

Las dudas que tengo son:

1. ¿Es correcta esta estructura para el objetivo que busco?
2. En caso afirmativo, ¿Por qué el error?

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar una matriz a un objeto de la clase `transactions`, la matriz tiene que tener estas condiciones:

- Cada columna debe ser una variable con valores 1 y 0
- Es conveniente que tenga nombres de fila y columna

El problema que estás teniendo es que estás transformando desde una matriz dónde la primer columna es el número de paciente, por lo que no se cumple el primer punto. Volviendo a la solución original que te dí, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
df <- read.table(text="Paciente     Patologia
 1         Sarcopenia
 1          Obesidad
 2          Sarcopenia
 2          Lupus
 2          Dolor", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

df %>% 
    mutate(valor=1) %>%                               # Agregamos un valor dummy
    spread(Patologia, valor, fill=0) %>%              # Esparcimos los valores de patolgia en nuevas columnas
    mutate(Paciente=paste("Paciente", Paciente)) %>%  # Reformateamos la columna Paciente
    column_to_rownames('Paciente') %>%                # Transformamos paciente en un rowname
    as.matrix() %>%                                   # Convertimos a matriz
    as("transactions") -> tr                          # Y ahora a transaction

tr
transactions in sparse format with
 2 transactions (rows) and
 4 items (columns)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho. Una duda: en el primer comando donde aparece "text =" tengo que introducir todos los datos del dataframe uno por uno? Cuando en lugar de eso introduzco el nombre del dataframe (df <- read.table(unico, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) me aparece el siguiente error: Error in read.table(unico, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: Hola @IkerVillanueva, mira, el `read.table` lo utilizo solo para importar el texto de ejemplo que has compartido, es decir a modo que mi respuesta quede reproducible para otros usuarios, puedes obviar esto y simplemente importar los datos como ya lo estás haciendo.